# Python replace special group of string using regex

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Currently my project runs on .net C# with 4.5.0 framework version. Which also integrated to use IronPython for some python script execution.
Now I am looking for replacing some special text from string with other e.g.

> PV1|1|??|??^^^??^^^??|||||??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??|??^??^??^??^^??^^^??
>   ??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^?~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??
>   ??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^???^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??|??||||||??^^^.^^^|??||??|||||||||||||||||||??||??|||??||||||
>
> ORC|??||??||||||??|^??^^^??^^^^??
>
> OBR|1|??^??|??^??|??^^^* ??|||??|??||||||||||||||??||??|??|||||||??|
>
> ZDS|??|^TEST^ONLY (TESTONLY)^^^TEST SUPPORT^^^^TEST|??|COMPLETED
>
> OBX|1|??|??^??

from above text I want to replace line for ZDS|??, with OBX|1|?? with rest of the string available in ZDS to be added to OBX. Also want to keep if any OBX string is available in the text as original OBX.

I tried below in Iron Python

```
import re

regEx = re.compile('^ZDS\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|\n\r ]+)')
Message = regEx.sub('OBX|1|FT|||\1~\2~\3~\4|||', Message)
```

Also

```
Message = re.sub(r'^ZDS\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|\n\r ]+)', 'OBX|1|FT|||\1~\2~\3~\4|||', Message, count=1)
```

and

```
Message= str.replace(Message, '^ZDS\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|\n\r ]+)','OBX|1|FT|||\1~\2~\3~\4|||')
```

But all above options did not worked.

I wanted output like

> PV1|1|??|??^^^??^^^??|||||??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??|??^??^??^??^^??^^^??
>   ??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^?~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??
>   ??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^???^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??|??||||||??^^^.^^^|??||??|||||||||||||||||||??||??|||??||||||
>
> ORC|??||??||||||??|^??^^^??^^^^??
>
> OBR|1|??^??|??^??|??^^^* ??|||??|??||||||||||||||??||??|??|||||||??|
>
> OBX|1|FT|||^TEST^ONLY (TESTONLY)^^^TEST SUPPORT^^^^TEST~??~COMPLETED
>
> OBX|1|??|??^??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got answer to my own question
Original message is 
Message =

```
PV1|1|??|??^^^??^^^??|||||??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??|??^??^??^??^^??^^^?? ??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^?~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^?? ??^^??^^^??~??^??^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^???^??^^^??^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??^??^^??^^^??^^^??^^??^^^??|??||||||??^^^.^^^|??||??|||||||||||||||||||??||??|||??||||||

ORC|??||??||||||??|^??^^^??^^^^??

OBR|1|??^??|??^??|??^^^* ??|||??|??||||||||||||||??||??|??|||||||??|

OBX|1|FT|||^TEST^ONLY (TESTONLY)^^^TEST SUPPORT^^^^TEST~??~COMPLETED

OBX|1|??|??^??
```

and in Python

```
import re

Message = re.sub(r'ZDS\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|\n\r ]+)', 'OBX|1|FT|||'+r'\1~\2~\3~\4|||', Message, count=1)
Message = re.sub(r'ZDS\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|\n\r ]+)', 'OBX|1|FT|||$1~$2~$3~$4|||', Message, count=1)
```